# List of the Prelude haskell operators, with precedence level

Tags: haskell, operators, operator-precedence, infix-operator

Where can I find a list of the infix Haskell operators in Prelude and base package in general, along with their precedence level, and whether they're right or left associative? I know this information is available in the documentation, but it's all spread out and mixed with descriptions and examples. I just want the list of these operators, without any descriptions, sorted by their precedence level and associativity. That is it.

Comment: Page 51 of the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) has a table of the prelude ones, but this does not include many other operators.

Comment: Is [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-prelude-1.6.1/docs/BasePrelude-Operators.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: Something that you might find useful is the `:i` command in GHCi (which is short for `:info`). It will, among other things, give you the precedence and associativity of an infix operator. For example, `:i -` gives you (at the end) `infixl 6 -`. In Haskell, `infixl` means left associative and `infixr` means right associative.

Comment: This is off-topic for a few reasons. Generally "Big List of X" questions aren't really great for this format; nobody wants to take on the burden of maintaining the list, so it quickly bitrots. Additionally, which operators are "popular" is a matter of opinion; for example, the lens library has hundreds of operators -- enough that they developed a grammar of operators to ease wetware memory requirements -- and it wouldn't surprise me if each of them had somebody out there that used that one all the time in their work.

Comment: @ddejohn: No. The precedences are out of order and mixed with descriptions and examples, exactly as I did not ask for.

Comment: The Haskell Report is exactly what I was looking for, @chi. Thanks.

Comment: `:i` was actually very helpful, @DavidYoung. I used it to automatically build the list. I will post the method and result as an answer when the question is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to generate this list automatically. First, write the operators to a file. Call it `ops`:

```
import Data.Function
import Data.Functor
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bits
:info $ $! . & : ++ !! <$ <$> $> >>= >> >=> <* <*> *> == /= < > <= >= && || + - * / `div` `mod` `divMod` `seq` ** ^ ^^ `elem` `notElem` .&. .|.
```

Then run the following:

```
> cat ops | ghci | grep infix | LC_ALL=C sort -s -k 2,2 -k 1,1
infixr 0 $
infixr 0 $!
infixr 0 `seq`
infixl 1 &
infixl 1 >>=
infixl 1 >>
infixr 1 >=>
infixr 2 ||
infixr 3 &&
infix 4 ==
infix 4 /=
infix 4 <
infix 4 >
infix 4 <=
infix 4 >=
infix 4 `elem`
infix 4 `notElem`
infixl 4 <$
infixl 4 <$>
infixl 4 $>
infixl 4 <*
infixl 4 <*>
infixl 4 *>
infixl 5 .|.
infixr 5 :
infixr 5 ++
infixl 6 +
infixl 6 -
infixl 7 *
infixl 7 /
infixl 7 `div`
infixl 7 `mod`
infixl 7 .&.
infixr 8 **
infixr 8 ^
infixr 8 ^^
infixr 9 .
>
```

Some operators won't appear in the output, because their fixity was unspecified. They have fixity `infixl 9`, which is the default. Notably, this includes `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

Page 51 of the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) has a table summarising the fixity of all Prelude operators.